# Ask for suggestion on a data structure usage

Tags: c++, data-structures

For each element in `data1`, I need to figure out what elements in `data2` are related to it. Also, for each element in `data2`, I need to figure out what elements in data1 are related to it. Therefore, I setup a mutual data structure as you can see below:

```
01  class data1 {
02    // class variables
03    int id;
04    float d1_v1;
05    float d1_v2;
06    map<string, float> m_to_data2; // string is the keyword of data2, float recorded the reference info when data1 and data2 are related.
07  };
08   
09  class data2 {
10    // class variables
11    int d2_v1;
      float d2_v2;
12    list <int> src_id;  // int is the id of data1
13  };
14   
15  map<string, data2 *> map_2;
16  map<int, data1 *> map_1;
```

Then I parse file and fill the map_1 and map_2. I found:

1. the total memory usage after setting up the mutual-linked two maps: 498.7M.
2. without set the link from data2 to data1 (not fill `list <int> src_id`), memory usage: 392.7M.
3. Without fill map_1, without fill `list <int> src_id` in data2, memory usage: 182.0M
4. Without fill map_1, fill `list <int> src_id` with ids of data1, memory usage: 289.7M
5. without fill map m_to_data2, memory usage: 290.0M
6. The size of map_1: 77737
7. The size of map_2: 1830009
8. The size of `map<string, float>` m_to_data2 for each element of map_1 in the range of 3 - 17522
9. The size of `list <int> src_id` for each element of map_2 in the range of 1- 1377

I need to reduce the memory usage after setting up the mutual-linked maps (ideally less than 200M, currently 498M as you can see above). I was trying to token the string (keyword of data2) to int by setting up an extra `map <string, int>`, since int needs less memory than string, but it may not help much since I need extra memory for the `map <string, int>`. Any suggestions?

Your comments/suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe store a pointer to data2 instead of the string for the keyword for the m_to_data2? Should save memory and CPU time.

Comment: How big are the actual objects (i.e. what is hidden in the `...`?) Are ids consecutive? (dense? sparse?) Simplest thing that you can do is changing the `list` to a `deque` if you do not need insertions-deletions in the middle (will avoid 2 pointers per object) or a `vector` if you can manage with just insertions-deletions at the end. You can replace the `maps` with hash maps to reduce the memory footprint, or if you can reuse ids and make them consecutive (and 0 based) then you can remove the extra cost of `map_1` by using a `vector` (hashmap with perfect hashing for some particular case)

Comment: (1) pointer needs the same memory as string, right? How can I save memory in that case?

Comment: no important stuffs in the ...., just two int variables. Those may not be the key issue to reduce the memory.

Comment: You should really work on your basics, you will not be able to optimize memory footprint if you don't understand the differences between a pointer and a string, and no, they do not take the same space. Each string has (potentially, depending on the compiler they might use copy-on-write semantics) its own copy of each stored character.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by the following:

- If possible (i.e. you have boost or tr1 available and ordering isn't important), change all `map`s to `unordered_map`s.
- If possible, change `list` in `data2` to `vector`.
- Have an `unordered_map` that maps from `string` to an `unsigned` `id` and use that `id` everywhere you're currently using strings. Given the size range of 3-17k for `m_to_data2`, you're duplicating names *a lot*.

Comment: Thanks, Pablo. (1) map the string to an id is what I am trying to do. Probably unsigned int would be a better idea. (2) I may need an ordered map since I need to find the element efficiently. I do search a lot in the following operation. (3) change list to vector can save memory? Maybe I did not understand them correctly, but I though list requires less memory than vector.

Comment: `list` stores at least a forward and backward pointer for each node, in addition to the stored value, whereas `vector` only stores the value.

Comment: `unordered_map`s allow for fast searching, faster even than ordered `map`s. `unordered_map`s are usually implemented using hash tables with `O(1)` lookup time, and `map`s are usually implemented using red-black trees with `O(lg n)` lookup time.

Comment: Thanks, Pablo, and David, I am going to read in the unordered_map and try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the float reference variable is taking up too much memory may be you can change it to a unsigned int.

Comment: `sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)` (in most common implementations both are 32bits) unless I have misunderstood your answer, changing the float to an int will not help at all.

Comment: You are right, sorry, I  was totally thinking of something else/.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. the reference needs to be float. What I mean is to map the string to an int, since int needs less memory than string. but that may not help much. Or any idea to setup the mutual-link database with less memory?

Comment: I may not be clear with the question but at the moment you may try out a multi-key map, key being unique, mapping two object from data 1 related to data 2. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, Wajih. You mean multimap?

Comment: Yes, multimap is what I meant

Comment: Wajih, as you can see my response above. I copied it here for your convenience. I looked through the doc of multimap, and found that the multimap may not work for me since I have 2 variables for data2, as you can see in the updated code above. Also, for now, I did not see some advantages for reducing memory usage when using multimap. It just allows multiple keys existing in the map (any others I did not see?). In this way, it may duplicate the key a lot, and may need more memory.

Comment: @Ke Peng, the catch here is to modify your "key" to make it unique, supposedly if you use two 32bit ints as separate keys, merge them as one (Store first int, left shift by 32 and OR the other int) this way it creates a unique key, then create the dictionary (multimap). and store the multiple values. Checkout this link http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0460__map-multimap/Multiplemap.htm   THis will also help you in maintaining a clean data structure. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly I would have rather used std::multimap instead of std::map

```
std::multimap<std::string, int> map2;
std::multimap<int, std::map<std::string, float> > map1;
```

that would make your code much easier to understand and proceed towards optimization.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Vink. I will look into multimap and see whether I can use it.

Comment: Hi Vink, I looked through the doc of multimap, and found that the multimap may not work for me since I have 2 variables for data2, as you can see in the updated code above. Also, for now, I did not see some advantages for reducing memory usage when using multimap. It just allows multiple keys existing in the map (any others I did not see?). In this way, it may duplicate the key a lot, and may need more memory.